# Are there any studies which investigate the usage of Caps-Lock?

Tags: keyboard

I've created a user interface which re-purposes the Caps Lock key to something more useful. During user studies some participants mentioned they did use the Caps Lock key from time to time. <sub>(Sidenote: I replaced the behavior of Caps Lock with Caps Lock - A)</sub>

**This made me wonder whether any research has been done about the usage of Caps Lock.**
Are there any usage statistics available? Which demographic uses it most?

It's [Humanized's project Enso](http://humanized.com/enso/), which inspired me to re-purpose the key for something more useful.

Jef Raskin (2000) proposed the removal of the Caps Lock key in ["The Humane Interface"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201379376). The [Chromebook](http://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/devices/features.html) went ahead [and actually did it](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/9699/3612), along with some other keys.

Comment: IT'S CERTAINLY GREAT FOR YELLING. But seriously, I would be just as happy if I could double-tap the shift key to activate caps lock and use that key for something else.

Answer (score 5):

Here on the Swiss keyboard we need the caps lock to write a capital Umlauts at the beginning of a sentence. E.g. pressing the ä-key with shift we get à. So we need caps lock and ä to get a Ä. So if you reprogram this key then we won't be able to write everything correctly. I guess there are other keyboard layouts where they use the caps lock in a similar way. So a lot of people will not be happy about it.

I can not give you any statistics or research results about this. Just my own experience.

Comment: It's always good to be reminded that not everyone writes purely in English on the web.

Comment: As long as you have `shift`, you'll never *need* `caps lock`.

Comment: @cornbreadninja I just showed you I need caps lock because there are some letters I can not press without it. Like uppercase umlauts.

Comment: *wow*, I misread that.  My apologies!

Comment: Oh god ... that seems even worse than Caps Lock itself. :) But thanks for pointing that out. In Belgium (and I presume France) we have an 'Alt Gr' key to type any third possible characters which are printed on the keys.

Comment: The 'Alt Gr' is for third characters printed on the keyboard as well. Those specific keys are for 4 different characters/symbols.

Comment: +1. To write Hebrew diacritic marks (*nikkud*) we press Caps Lock, then Shift + one of the numbers.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't a study, but [this article](http://www.slate.com/articles/life/culturebox/2012/02/caps_lock_has_to_go_and_other_proposals_for_improving_the_computer_keyboard.html) provides a lot of insight. Some examples of Caps Lock lovers the article mentions are those with disabilities that make it difficult to press two keys at once and engineers, who frequently use all caps for clarity.

I would recommend instead of asking your users if they do caps lock, watch how often they do it during user testing. Even if they do use it from time to time, if your users aren't a high-use group, you can probably do away with it.